# "Link" two cells, modify one changes the other

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, dropdownlist

I have a dataset that I use to generate some graphs. I have a cell in one sheet that changes my data based on the country I choose from a dropdown. I want to be able to change this dropdown from a separate worksheet.

So I'd have:
Sheet 1 -> Data, Graph, Drop Down
Sheet 2 -> Graph, Drop Down

I need to make it so that if I change the drop down in sheet 2, it changes the value of the drop down in the sheet 1, and vice versa. How can I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, you're not changing the value of the drop-down, you're just changing the value of the cell, and it's quite easy.

You'll put a formula in the cell you want to automatically update based on the selection in the cell you actually select in, and that formula simply takes the selected value from that first cell and uses it in the second:

Let's say you are working in Cell **A1** in Worksheet **Sheet1** and you want the selection here to show up in Cell **B2** in Worksheet **Sheet2**:

Simply place the following formulate in cell B2 in Sheet2:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

This will take any values entered or selected in Sheet1 A1 and place them in Sheet2 B2.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I did not explain myself correctly. Using your example, I need to have the capacity to change the value in Sheet2,B2 and that that would affect the value in Sheet1 as well. Basically I'm just looking for that cell to be the same across both sheets, but that it would change values regardless of in which sheet I change the value of it.

Comment: Oh, I missed the vice-versa bit. That'll be a macro that triggers based on updates in those fields. You'll want to make sure the OnUpdate is written so that it doesn't trigger on the macro's update itself.